# Assembly draw line function

Tags: assembly, graphics, osdev

So, In my OS, I created a put pixel function. Im trying to make a draw line function with it.

here's my code:

```
org 0x7e00
[bits 16]

_start:

    mov ah, 0x00   ; Set Video Mode
    mov al, 0x03   ; Mode 3 (80x25 characters)
    int 0x10       ; Call BIOS interrupt

    mov ax,0x13
    int 0x10

    jmp EnterPM

%include "../src/system/include/gdt.asm"

EnterPM:
    call EnableA20
    cli

    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp codeseg:StartProtectedMode

EnableA20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    ret

[bits 32]

VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
GRAPHICS_MEMORY equ 0x0A0000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f
PINK_ON_BLACK equ 0x3f

StartProtectedMode:

    mov ax, dataseg
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov eax, 10
    mov ecx, 0
    mov ebx, PINK_ON_BLACK
    mov edx, 70
    call draw_line

    jmp $

;------------------------------
;                             |
;   put_pixel method          |
;   Plot a pixel on the screen|
;                             |
;   Arguments:                |
;   eax - pos_x               |
;   ecx - pos_y               |
;   ebx - color               |
;                             |
;   kappetrov created         |
;-----------------------------|
put_pixel:
    ; Calculate memory address of pixel
    mov edi, GRAPHICS_MEMORY       ; Base address of graphics memory
    imul ecx, ecx, 320             ; Multiply pos_y by 320 (assuming 320 pixels per scanline)
    add edi, ecx                   ; Add offset for y
    add edi, eax                   ; Add offset for x

    ; Move color into memory
    mov eax, ebx                   ; Move color value into eax for consistency
    mov [edi], eax                 ; Store color value at calculated memory address

    ret                            ; Return from function

; eax = pos x, ecx = pos y, edx = width, ebx = color
draw_line:

    cmp edx, 0
    je exit

    call put_pixel
    inc eax
    dec edx
    jmp draw_line
    ret

exit:
    ret

times 512-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

It's not actually drawing a line, sure, it's drawing 2 pixels indicating it's a line, but it doesnt actually draw the pixels between them.

i tried to draw a line, it did draw 2 pixels indicating a line, but doesnt draw the individual pixels between them.

Comment: No, edx you could say is my loop counter.

Comment: eax, is the position x, i increment it so the next pixel draws beside the already drawn pixel.

Comment: Yes, but you are incrementing EAX in draw_line but each time you call put_pixel you clobber it with color.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: `mov eax, ebx` `mov [edi], eax` overwrites EAX in the `put_pixel` function, but I don't know why you are doing that since you can just do `mov [edi], ebx`. It is unclear why you move it into EAX first

Comment: Oh yeah, actually, i implemented it a different way at first, but someone in my team rewrote it. Thanks for the help, it works now.

Comment: `imul ecx, ecx, 320` will destroy the value of `ecx` in general case, but it should work with `ecx = 0`...